# Strange bug in cocos2d-x

Tags: uikit, cocos2d-x

I have found one bug that causes the cocos2d view to stop rendering its contents. The bug can be reproduced using the example project found in  Jpsarda's post about integration between UIKit and cocos2d-x.
The link to the website is: http://jpsarda.tumblr.com/post/24983791554/mixing-cocos2d-x-uikit and the link to the project is: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12856650/Cocos2dxOnUikit.zip.

To reproduce the bug it is sufficient to trigger several times between uikit views and cocos2d views by pressing repeatedly the "Cocos2d-x GO!" button on the first view followed by the "Close" button on the second view. I have also done a video that shows how to reproduce the bug: http://youtu.be/EIvf-Ao6u5I. The bug occurs only on a real device and not on the simulator. Because of this bug it is pretty difficult to create applications that allow the user to switch frequently between cocos2d views and uikit views such the one on which I am working. For the moment I can't understand the root cause and I haven't received a reply on the forum yet. Is there anyone that have an idea/intution/suggestion about the possible cause?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason. EAGLView is never released and this causes a leak of resources. To resolve the bug in JPSARDA's example it is sufficient to add the following line:

[[EAGLView sharedEGLView] release];

at the end of CCEGELView::release method. This will solve JPSARDA's ( and my application :D ) issues but it is likely that this solution won't work in projects that handle EAGLView's lifecycle in a different way